# Re: select which PHP variables to emit for android

Tags: php, android, httpresponse

I use HttpResponse to capture a JSON from a PHP script (call it script #1). The script emits the JSON via print_r().

Problem : the PHP incldues a script (call it script #2) which also uses print_r to emit a variable. I also use this script independently in another part of my program.
The issue is that my httpResponse function in android captures the print_r emission in script #2 rather than the print_r in script #1. How can I work around this?

Here is the outline of what's happening:
Script #2 (contains a print_r)-> script #1 (uses data in #2 and emits a print_r)-> Android HttpResponse collects print_r from #2 instead of from #1.

Comment: Quite simply do not print from script 2.  The response is going to parse the first JSON it gets.

Comment: Hi Michael, how do you reconcile your response with the fact that I need to print_r from script 2 for other usages? Should I build a 3rd script that handles print_r for script 2?

Comment: you should perhaps make it that whatever you are calling has an argument that makes the printing to stdout optional.